# Installing QGIS with GRASS plugin on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, ubuntu

I already tried to install QGIS 2.8.3 using the procedure  described on:
http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubunt,  but grass-plugin do not compare on plugin list!

I tried both repositories: ubuntugis or debian, but nothing!
I also cleaned the previous QGIS 2.6 installation (remove old ppa) on my UBUNTU 14.04.

Does anyone tell me a complete and verified fresh procedure (step by step) to do a good install that allows grass-plugin (grass 6 or 7 it's the same)?

19 ago update :
I've done exactly this steps (before I cleaned previos install and repositories):
    sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
    sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main'
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3
    gpg --export --armor DD45F6C3 | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass grass-gui grass-doc

So, I correctly installed : QGIS 2.10.1, GRASS 6.4.2 and gras-plugin working !!
But ... mysteriously in grass-toolbar:  "add raster layer"  and "add vector layer" do not compare !! ....I d'nt understand.
What's the matter ?

[image: qgis snapshot]

Using repository 'http://qgis.org/debian trusty main', it is installed the Qgis 2.10 release ... if I am not mistaken !

If it's possible instead, I want to install Qgis 2.8.3 LTR with grass-plugin working  (GRASS 6 or 7 it'snt important).

Comment: Do you want to use v 2.8.3 specifically, or do you want to install the latest v 2.10?

Comment: If it's possibile I prefer 2.8.3 release; anyway the important thing is that grass plugin working !!

Comment: Please edit to indicate which GRASS GIS version you want to connect to: GRASS 6 or7?

Answer (score 2):

To install the lastest stable QGIS and GRASS 6 I use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main'
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3
gpg --export --armor DD45F6C3 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass grass-gui grass-doc
```

The keycodes are taken from the [QGIS page](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). You'll then need to turn on the GRASS plugin in the QGIS plugins menu. You can wrap this up in an install script so each time you have a fresh install you can run the script you wrote previously, an example of my own is [here](https://scottishsnow.wordpress.com/software/).

Comment: It seems like there's been a dependency problem somewhere... because I have `qgis-plugin-grass` installed, but when I followed the instructions on your website, I didn't have `grass-core` installed.

Comment: I haven't done a rebuild since April 2015, the script I used to install grass is the one on the answer. Possibly a problem has arisen since then, but I've never specifically installed `grass-core`.

Comment: I must've done `apt-get autoremove` and it was removed... `qgis-plugin-grass` doesn't *currently* depend on grass-core (maybe it shouldn't?), but a loading error message I was getting in QGIS stopped when I installed `grass-core`

Answer (score 2):

I  solved the problem in this way ....
First, I removed all QGIS packages and its dependencies, but not **Grass 6.4.3.** !!
I also changed debian repository (in /etc/apt/sources.list) from 'deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main' to 'deb http://qgis.org/debian-ltr trusty main' (so I can install QGIS 2.8 LTR).
Then I followed these steps :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

So I finally installed, on **Ubuntu 14.04**, QGIS 2.8.3 with grass-plugin (for Grass 6) perfectly working !!