# QGIS 2.10 with ubuntugis dependecies Grass issues Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I saw in [Installing QGIS with GRASS plugin on Ubuntu?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158438/how-to-correctly-install-qgis-2-8-3-with-grass-plugin-on-ubuntu-14-04) how to get Qgis 2.10 running from the non ubuntugis repository with grass features but I'm still having problems with getting it to work with the ubuntugis unstable dependencies.  I have tried using 2.10, 2.8.3, and the nightly build but can neither get the GRASS plugin toolbar to work or the new browser to show the grass files like the video shows [here](http://www.gissula.eu/qgis-grass-plugin-crowdfunding/progress.html).  While I can get work done with the standard install I like having using the ubuntugis dependencies and packages for work with postgis, spatialite, etc and would really like to have it all gel together rather than have multiple repositories that may confuse each other.  So after all of that filler I guess my question would be has anybody got QGIS 2.10's grass tools(both processing and plugin) to work with the ubuntugis dependencies and if so how?

Comment: I've got it working following installation instructions I modified from the main QGIS debian/ubuntu install instructions - you can find them here: https://github.com/mapbaker/QGIS-Website/blob/master/source/site/forusers/alldownloads.rst But they pull from the main QGIS repository, which I think is the best to pull from...

Comment: Can you see if `grass-core` is installed? I have the same problem and found that while `qgis-plugin-grass` was installed, `grass-core` was not.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it with grass-core installed and still nada, don't know if it's a do it in a certain sequence and the magic doors open or not.  Sounds more and more like it is a bug that needs to be worked out.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some trouble with GRASS 6/7 support as a plugin and in processing:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2015-July/038601.html

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2015-August/033174.html

I guess you have to downgrade and follow the mailing lists for any progress.

Comment: Yeah I had seen that there were some issues but didn't know the extent went this far.  I followed the first advice article and installed without ubuntugis and everything is fine.  I will wait til the issues get sorted out to go back to using those dependencies.  Hopefully they will do it in a point release rather than the next version.