# 2.10 program group option to open QGIS with GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, windows-8

I have installed QGIS 2.10 on Windows 8.

I cannot find the 'option' to start QGIS with GRASS - as has been previously answered.

Have I possibly missed something in the install? Is this 'missing' from Windows 8

Comment: GRASS support is currently broken. see my answer in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159125/qgis-2-10-with-ubuntugis-dependecies-grass-issues-ubuntu-14-04 and follow the given links.

Answer (score 2):

I have only win 7, but I think in win 8 it is similar.

option 1: Open the program group qgis pisa , you will see something like this:

[image]

option 2: search for "qgis" you will see something like this:
[image]