# TauDEM tools in QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa (Ubuntu 15) are not in the Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, taudem

My TauDEM tools have disappeared in my latest version of QGIS.

Any ideas how to get them back? They used to be in the processing Tab.

Using
QGIS 2.10.1
TauDEM
Ubuntu 14 stable

My other tools are there (Gdal, grass, etc)

[This](https://github.com/rozos/TauDEM-QGIS) appears to be the instructions but I am not really linux strong enough to follow them.

For example, Number 1. Uninstall openmpi-common (causes conflicts) and install mpich2.

Comment: Curious how you installed this the first time? Not much documentation is out there from what I can find...

Comment: Me too. I used this method to install (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158438/how-to-correctly-install-qgis-2-8-3-with-grass-plugin-on-ubuntu-14-04) The top answer.

Comment: I did find this https://github.com/rozos/TauDEM-QGIS

Comment: so it comes with GRASS??

Comment: not it is not a GRASS Tool it is its own thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about TauDEM on Ubunto, actually, I don't know much about it on Windows, but I can say that in windows, you need to select the Processing/Options/Providers.  TauDEM should be there.  Open it and select activate.   Once activated, it should be visible in the Processing/Toolbox/Advanced interface.

It took me a couple of days to find it, so I'm not sure if TauDEM was there natively or because of something else I did, like go to the TauDEM site and download the installer and installed it.  Either way, I now have it.  Having trouble running it, but that's my problem.  Hope it helps you.