# GRASS plugin missing from QGIS 2.14.3 Essen in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis-2.14, qgis-grass-plugin

I had installed QGIS 2.14.0 (or .1 not sure) and I did some work with the GRASS plugin a couple of months ago, so it was there.

I upgraded a couple of weeks ago to **QGIS 2.14.3** and I was planning in using the **GRASS plugin is now missing**.

**GRASS is installed and works from the Processing tools**, but the plugin is not to be found anywhere... (and yes the I have installed the plugin with sudo apt-get install qgis-plugin-grass)

[image: . My setup]

I have been looking for a solution and none of the ones I found seem to work. The closest one was [this one but none the answers changed the situation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158438/how-to-correctly-install-qgis-2-8-3-with-grass-plugin-on-ubuntu-14-04).

(System: GRASS70, QGIS 2.14.3 Essen in Ubuntu 14.04)

**Update:** I found out that the grass-plugins that I have in my machine are "libgrassplugin6.so, libgrassprovider6.so and libgrassrasterprovider6.so". So the problem seems to be that I have GRASS 7 installed but the plugin is for GRASS 6, right?

**Update2:** I found [this question in the users list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GRASS7-Plugin-for-QGIS-2-12-on-Ubuntu-td5236606.html) (sorry I did not look earlier) and seems to be the same/similar problem... from the answers there you don't quite find the solution but I am working on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! Hope it helps others.

First thing was to find out what the real problem is. I would think that the problem is likely that **I ended up having repositories (somehow changed them in between updates to QGIS) which leads me to have GRASS 7 installed with a QGIS version trying to use a qgis-grass-plugin for GRASS 6**... See the question and updates in above.

Solution, find the correct repositories and update as necessary until you have a consistent set of versions. That is, GRASS 7 and qgis-grass-plugin for verion 7... and make all of the packages have the same version!

I started with these repositories: # deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
**and** # deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main.

**First comment those two out** (or the ones you have).

And **then add those highlighted in the picture**... you can find those in the [QGIS installation pages](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#linux).

**Then update the list using for example Synaptic or via the terminal**. You can see in the left side of the picture that I have already updated the list but still have the **libqgisgrass6-xx packages active** and the **libqgisgrass7-2.14.3 waiting for installation**.

[image: starting repositories and fixed ones]

After **installing the libraries referencing GRASS 6 and installing the one for version 7 you would probably there... here is the situation now** (but see below for an additional possible complication)

[image]

**I still had the problem that the grass-core package was still 7.03 while the rest of grass packages were 7.04... upgrade that too or you will not have the grass-plugin available yet.**

In this picture you can see that I have already upgraded grass-core to 7.04 and now I can finally use the GRASS 7 plugin in QGIS 2.14.3!

[image]

Comments? experiences?

Comment: I tried to do this solution in qgis 2.14.4 but it wasn't work well.

Comment: Hi Diogo, what was your result? in the end my problem was caused (I think) by different versions of grass installed.

Comment: this solution worked, but it update to qgis 2.18.x possibly because my repos are messed up. but i tried this soln here https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10714 and now grass plugin in the processing toolbox works alright!