# QGIS 2.18 Windows 10, 32 bit system - where is the GRASS plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-7.0, qgis-grass-plugin, grass-7.2

I checked these question/answers already, but they did not address my issue:

- [GRASS plugin missing from QGIS 2.14.3 Essen in Ubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198483/grass-plugin-missing-from-qgis-2-14-3-essen-in-ubuntu-14-04?newreg=9943b9f3a6584aa691fc085133fbe4dc)
- [How do I get grass plugin working in QGIS for Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214159/how-do-i-get-grass-plugin-working-in-qgis-for-windows)

I am on a Windows 10 sytem, 64 bit. I installed QGIS 2.18 (also 2.14 and 2.16 to try to resolve the issue). The GRASS plugin is simply NOT THERE. So, when I go into the program files of QGIS 2.18 and look in the apps folder it says GRASS 7.2.0 is installed. For QGIS 2.16 the apps folder has GRASS 7.0.4. Finally, the QGIS 2.14 has GRASS 7.0.4.

I search for GRASS in the plugin console and it's missing! What am I doing wrong?
[image]

I am not a developer, so I cannot troubleshoot at the code level...

Comment: GRASS is a processing feature it is in the 'Processing Toolbox' http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/_images/toolbox_advanced.png When QGIS is installed it is already there.

Comment: Hello Mapperz, if I understand you correctly, you mean that the plugin is no longer required in the later versions of QGIS?

Comment: That is correct both GDAL and GRASS are part of the package now

Comment: Many thanks! This simple question was impossible to find an answer to online. I suspected it, but needed confirmation. Furthermore, it's really difficult to ascertain how to use GRASS now since most of the material refers to this plugin... A new user will certainly get confused...

Comment: The Processing Toolbox is very similar to the 'ArcGIS Geoprocessing Toolbox' (if you have come from ESRI side of software)

Comment: Hi, the solution above may be incorrect. It seems that I can access the GRASS plugin now, as long as I select the QGIS Desktop 2.18.3 with GRASS 7.2.0 from my Windows 10 search bar. Previously, I was selecting only: "QGIS Desktop 2.18.3". It made all the difference.

Comment: If that was your solution then I think you should post it as an answer. It is fine to self-answer.

Answer (score 3):

The GRASS plugin is available when you open QGIS Desktop with GRASS instead of QGIS Desktop.From the plugin then you can access GRASS.

Answer (score -2):

download 2.18.1 qgis for 32bit