# No Grass plugin in plugin manager in Qgis 2.14 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.14, grass-7.2

I have installed QGIS 2.14.15-Essen and GRASS GIS 7.2.1, but  there is no option to add GRASS plugin in Plugin Manager

Comment: Check [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198483/grass-plugin-missing-from-qgis-2-14-3-essen-in-ubuntu-14-04) for a solution to the missing plugin

Comment: Can't reproduce it on Mint 18 (based on xenial) with clean install `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass` from repository `http://qgis.org/debian-ltr` and neither with ubuntugis dependencies `http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr` (which install GRASS 7.2). Can you provide more information? How did you install QGIS and GRASS? Did you install `qgis-plugin-grass`?

Answer (score 1):

Within QGIS, you should access GRASS functionality using the Processing Toolbox (`Processing --> Toolbox` or Ctrl+Alt+T) and not the Plugin Manager. When the Toolbox opens, you should have access to all of the GRASS modules:
[image]

It is also worth checking that the GRASS provider is activated within QGIS (`Processing --> Processing Options --> Providers --> GRASS GIS 7 commands`).

While version 2.14 is the LTR, you might consider installing a more recent version, e.g. 2.18.9.

Comment: *"...and not the Plugin Manager."* This is a little misleading, since OP asked about GRASS plugin (not processing toolbox implementation) which should be appearing in Plugin manager.