# QGIS with GRASS on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ubuntu

Following the advice on [Installing QGIS with GRASS plugin on Ubuntu?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158438/how-to-correctly-install-qgis-2-8-3-with-grass-plugin-on-ubuntu-14-04)...

I've installed qgis, qgis-plugin-grass, python-qgis, grass-core=6.4.3-3, grass=6.4.3-3, grass-doc=6.4.3-3, grass-gui=6.4.3-3

I open qgis, but there is nothing about GRASS in the plugins menu.

```
scott@beast:~$ apt-cache policy qgis
qgis:
  Installed: 2.8.3-0~trusty1
  Candidate: 2.8.3-0~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.3-0~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.1-2build2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
scott@beast:~$ apt-cache policy grass
grass:
  Installed: 6.4.3-3
  Candidate: 7.0.1-1~exp1~trusty
  Version table:
     7.0.1-1~exp1~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 6.4.3-3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```